# configure : error: PAM headers not found (for nios2 linux based on uClinux

Tags: linux, embedded, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, gnu

I am cross-compiling ucLinux for an Altera chip based board (nios2-linux). I want to include the PAM functionality, hence I enabled that option in .config file. I encountered compile errors when corresponding application openssh includes pam functionality by the autoconf functionality(I am not familiar with this), it uses the `configure.ac/configure..etc` files in `user/ssh` directory where it resides.

I did a google search and found recommendation to do `yum install pam-devel` however I still this error

```
configure: error: PAM headers not found. (this is due to it not finding security/pam_appl.h)
```

The `configure.ac` for some reason is not able to find `security/pam_appl.h` even when the find command on my filesystem finds it in the nios2-linux distribution I am using (`/home/mannydev/nios2-linux/uClinux-dist/lib/libpam/Linux-PAM-0.99.3.0/libpam/include/security`). I copied all the pam header files in lib/libpam/libpam,libpamc,libpam_misc to user/ssh but to no avail.

I encounter similar compilation errors when I enable PAM feature in Busybox, the culprit seems to be the security/pam_appl.h not found`.
Can someone help me for both user/openssh problem and busybox problem?
The embedded Linux variant I am using is linux-2.6.x in the distribution I have and is based on uCLinux (nios2-linux).

Comment: correction : for busybox the culprit is security/pam_appl.h  not found. Also for openssh the configure.ac where I get the PAM header error is the test of x$ac_cv_header_security_pam_appl_h which fails

Comment: user/ssh/configure checks for libpam - checking for pam_set_item in -lpam... no configure: error: *** libpam missing. This is where compilation fails.

Comment: Have tried [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/)? AFAIK it has PAM stuff and toolchains for nios2 and a lot of other packages.

Comment: I have not tried buildroot yet.